# MYSQL search returns all results in the table no matter what is searched

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, search

The code below pairs with the HTML to search the db for the results. It is supposed to search based on what is entered into the search field. I had posted a question and got a lot of great responses about SQL injection, so I have updated my code.

**CODE OPTION 1 I TRIED**
If I just press the search button with the field empty, it returns every result in the table. If I put something into the field, it still returns every result in the table. It doesn't matter what is put in the field, all this code seems to do is return every result in the table. Where have I gone wrong where the search doesnt work?

```
function my_function_name() {
global $wpdb;

$search = trim($_POST['search']);
$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable name WHERE columnname LIKE '%%%s%%'", $search);
$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);

if($results)

{echo json_encode($results); /* echo 'added'; */}
```

else{ echo 'no results found'; } die; }

**CODE OPTION 2 I TRIED**
If I just press the search button with the field empty, it returns echos 'no results found' which is my else{ code. If I put something into the field, it still says the same thing. Doesnt matter what I put in there

```
function my_function_name() {           

global $wpdb;
$search = $_POST['search'];
$wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix} mytable WHERE id = %d AND columnname = %s", $id, $secret);


if($results)

{echo json_encode($results); /* echo 'added'; */}

else{ echo 'no results found'; } die; }
```

The HTML

```
<form action="<?php echo admin\_url('/admin-ajax.php'); ?>" method="post" id="ajax\_my\_function\_id" autocomplete="off">

Search <input type="text" name="search"><br>
<input type ="submit">

</form>
```

Comment: Are you searching the default WP tables? And what are you searching for - e.g. post content? Its difficult for us to know why your query isn't returning what you expect when we don't how what your db contains and what you expect it to return!

Comment: Hi thanks. I am searching custom tables with different table names than posted above. I was trying to make this general for people in the future instead of too specific to my issue. I am searching for the id as an INT or searching for a activation code as a string. Hoping that helps?

Comment: did you mean you create your own table? and you will try search it ?

Comment: did you tried this ? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8825/how-do-you-properly-prepare-a-like-sql-statement

Comment: I understand trying to make the question general, but we still need enough information to be able to help :). Its difficult to help debug SQL queries because they depend entirely on your table structure & content and the values in your variables. Also the 2 SQL queries in your question are very different - one returns everything that partially matches any column name, the other looks for a specific value in a specific column - so we don't know even what you're searching for. All I can suggest is to start of getting a query that runs as expected directly in your database, and work from there.

Comment: With your second attempt, you are not even _using_ the variable `$search` anywhere in your query. (And instead, you are using two variables `$id` and `$secret` which, should that be the actual code, most likely do not even exist in the current scope.)

Comment: @jerson thanks. It is just a custom table. All msyql functions. It returns results from the table ok, just doesnt seem to search the table

Comment: @04fs thanks yea I saw that. I had tried that based on a suggestion but didnt expect it to work.

Comment: @fluffykitten thanks and I understand. I know everything is good with teh table etc, it is just the way I am trying to search it. That is what isnt working. What can I provide that may allow someone to help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be it cannot identifies the format specifier properly as it is within multiple % sign. Use concatenation operator.

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable name WHERE columnname LIKE '%%' . $search . '%%'");
```